# Retrieve values on server side from tag-it input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, http

I'm using [tag-it](http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/js/tag-it.js) plugin and the trouble is to get the values selected on server side. The tags are put into `item[tags][]` and I hardly see how I can retreive those values on server side in my controller.
The post form data looks like this : `item%5Btags%5D%5B%5D` and then goes the string with the name of the tag.
The question is how do I name the variable on the server side so I can access those tag values. It should look something like `string[] tags` I think.

---

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried Request.Form on the server-side?

Comment: Reques.Form.Keys[3] gives me "item[tags][]" key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Think I made it myself. I added model binder for "item[tags][]" key. And it now works just fine. Looks like this `[Bind(Prefix = "item[tags][]")] string[] tags`

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

In markup

```
 <ul id="ul_Tags" name="ul_Tags"></ul>
```

In code-behind

```
 string[] tags = Request.Form["ul_Tags"].Split(',');
```